# python 3 simplejson dumps turns django query dict keys to lowercase

Tags: python, django

python 3.7 
I have a POST request that returns a query dict in django like this

```
<QueryDict: {'tbl': ['[{"Unnamed: 0":"0","RecordID":"0","ID":"1","Site Ser
ved":"51st Street Academy","Program":"Outreach","Boro":"Queens","Manager":"Steve
 Waters","Event Date":"2019-11-19","Address":"7605 51st Street ","Zip":"11373","
Activity":"Word on the Street\\n","Grc":"42","ErrorMsg":"ADDRESS NUMBER OUT OF R
ANGE","Version":"18D","Suggested Corrected Address":"76-05 51st Ave, Elmhurst, N
Y 11373"},{"Unnamed: 0":"1","RecordID":"2","ID":"3","Site Served":"Cardinal Spel
lman High School","Program":"Outreach","Boro":"Brooklyn","Manager":"Lee Eastmond
","Event Date":"2019-11-04","Address":"1 Cardinal Spellman Place","Zip":"10466",
"Activity":"Alive at 25","Grc":"EE","ErrorMsg":"1 CARDINAL SPELLMAN PLACE NOT RE
COGNIZED. THERE ARE 009 SIMILAR NAMES.","Version":"18D","Suggested Corrected Add
ress":"1 Cardinal Spellman Pl, The Bronx, NY 10466"},{"Unnamed: 0":"2","RecordID
":"37","ID":"38","Site Served":"St. Marks Day  School","Program":"Outreach","Bor
o":"Brooklyn","Manager":"Steve Waters","Event Date":"2019-11-06","Address":"1346
 Presidnt Street","Zip":"11213","Activity":"My Safety Toolbox\\nSafety Smarts","
Grc":"11","ErrorMsg":"1346 PRESIDNT STREET NOT RECOGNIZED. THERE ARE NO SIMILAR
NAMES","Version":"18D","Suggested Corrected Address":"1346 President St, Brookly
n, NY 11213"}]']}>
```

i then run

`simplejson.dumps(variable_holding_query_dict)`

and it for some reason lowercases the keys

```
'{"tbl": "[{\\"unnamed:0\\":\\"0\\",\\"recordid\\":\\"0\\",\\"id\\":\\"1\\
",\\"siteserved\\":\\"51st Street Academy\\",\\"program\\":\\"Outreach\\",\\"bor
o\\":\\"Queens\\",\\"manager\\":\\"Steve Waters\\",\\"eventdate\\":\\"2019-11-19
\\",\\"address\\":\\"7605 51st Street \\",\\"zip\\":\\"11373\\",\\"activity\\":\
\"Word on the Street\\\\n\\",\\"grc\\":\\"42\\",\\"errormsg\\":\\"ADDRESS NUMBER
 OUT OF RANGE\\",\\"version\\":\\"18D\\",\\"suggestedcorrectedaddress\\":\\"76-0
5 51st Ave, Elmhurst, NY 11373\\"},{\\"unnamed:0\\":\\"1\\",\\"recordid\\":\\"2\
\",\\"id\\":\\"3\\",\\"siteserved\\":\\"Cardinal Spellman High School\\",\\"prog
ram\\":\\"Outreach\\",\\"boro\\":\\"Brooklyn\\",\\"manager\\":\\"Lee Eastmond\\"
,\\"eventdate\\":\\"2019-11-04\\",\\"address\\":\\"1 Cardinal Spellman Place\\",
\\"zip\\":\\"10466\\",\\"activity\\":\\"Alive at 25\\",\\"grc\\":\\"EE\\",\\"err
ormsg\\":\\"1 CARDINAL SPELLMAN PLACE NOT RECOGNIZED. THERE ARE 009 SIMILAR NAME
S.\\",\\"version\\":\\"18D\\",\\"suggestedcorrectedaddress\\":\\"1 Cardinal Spel
lman Pl, The Bronx, NY 10466\\"},{\\"unnamed:0\\":\\"2\\",\\"recordid\\":\\"37\\
",\\"id\\":\\"38\\",\\"siteserved\\":\\"St. Marks Day  School\\",\\"program\\":\
\"Outreach\\",\\"boro\\":\\"Brooklyn\\",\\"manager\\":\\"Steve Waters\\",\\"even
tdate\\":\\"2019-11-06\\",\\"address\\":\\"1346 Presidnt Street\\",\\"zip\\":\\"
11213\\",\\"activity\\":\\"My Safety Toolbox\\\\nSafety Smarts\\",\\"grc\\":\\"1
1\\",\\"errormsg\\":\\"1346 PRESIDNT STREET NOT RECOGNIZED. THERE ARE NO SIMILAR
 NAMES\\",\\"version\\":\\"18D\\",\\"suggestedcorrectedaddress\\":\\"1346 Presid
ent St, Brooklyn, NY 11213\\"}]"}'
```

how do i not have it return lowercase keys.

I need the original case the POST request returns so I cannot go the route of creating a new dict with the keys being any case i want

Comment: try `json.dumps(your_dictionary)`

Comment: can you provide your html and views.py code

Comment: Honestly, this behavior is pretty strange. The value of `tbl` is a **string**. So it should not be modified when serialized (other than being properly escaped). Are you sure there are no other operations being performed prior to serializing it to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about it?:

```
import json

json.dumps(variable_holding_query_dict.dict())
```

example:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
import json


qd = QueryDict('', mutable=True) # just a dummy QD example
qd.update({'example': 'UPPERCASE', 'example2': 'any value'})
json.dumps(qd.dict())
```

JSON dump result:

> '{"example": "UPPERCASE", "example2": "any value"}'

Comment: The OP is asking about serializing a QueryDict not a model instance.

Comment: Answer updated. I don't notice that @DanielMorell, thanks.